# Get a remote FLV using PHP and curl

Tags: php, curl, exec

I want to know if it's possible to get a remote flv file and have it 'stream' using PHP and exec function. I have 'curl' in my environnement so i want something like :

```
exec ('curl http://myhosts.com/myflv.flv', $out);
print $out;
```

Problem is that $out is returned as an array; i want to output the 'raw' stream returned by curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [fpassthru()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php) for that, although it would probably be better to just redirect the user to the proper URL instead.

```
$fp = fopen('http://myhosts.com/myflv.flv', 'rb');
fpassthru($fp);
```

Or redirect:

```
header('Location: http://myhosts.com/myflv.flv');
```

Come to think of it, you should even be able to use [readfile()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

```
readfile('http://myhosts.com/myflv.flv');
```

At any rate, if you can simply redirect the user, do that. It's way more efficient.

Comment: Well, first option seems to work. My next deal is the PHP execution max timeout; if my flv is really big, php will obviously timeout. What would be another alternatives you think ?

Comment: First off, when you say "my flv" I assume you're still talking about remote files. If the file is accessible locally, you should most definitely access it locally. Secondly, while redirecting using a `Location` header is still the method to prefer, it is my understanding that the max execution timeout cannot stop the execution of a PHP function, therefore it cannot stop `readfile()` or `fpassthru()`

Comment: The FLV's are hosted on another server the only way that i have to access them is thru web ... will try your recommendations. Thanks.